# Is a higher masturbation frequency correlated with suffering of schizophrenia?

Tags: sexuality, masturbation

[LivingWithSchizophrenia](http://www.livingwithschizophreniauk.org/causes/) writes:

> It was widely believed during the 19th and early 20th centuries, when sexual mores were very much stricter than today, that masturbation caused schizophrenia

Offline I heared that the average masturbation frequency of people with schizophrenia is much higher than that of the general population.

Is that sentiment that schizophrenia correlatees with higher than average masturbation frequency true? Do we have studies about the amount of masturbation of patient suffering under schizophrenia that show that their rate doesn't differ from the normal population?

Comment: I've never heard this claim. Could you add some sources to establish *present-day* notability?

Comment: @Anko : LivingWithSchizophrenia certainly makes the claim that the link doesn't exist with present-day notability. On [R/NoFap](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoFap/comments/1ijexo/could_pmo_promote_schizophrenia/) I do find on Schizophrenia "This is a touchy subject because nobody wants to give medical/professional advice on Reddit. In my personal opinion I think it could be good for regulating it." I think a sizeable portion of the NoFap community holds such a view but the explicit claims are generally more vague.

Comment: Do 30 year old basement dwellers obsessed with anime and gaming have higher rates of schizophrenia than the rest of the population?